# Unable to print git commit hash (using git --pretty) when runing inside a Makefile

Tags: git, shell, makefile

I am trying to get the version (first 7 characters of the commit hash) of a file using the "git --pretty" format inside a Makefile.

Below is my Makefile

```
#CUR_LOC_VERSION:= $(shell git log --pretty=format:%H -n1 -- | grep -o '^.\{7\}') # works
CUR_LOC_VERSION:= $(shell git log --pretty=format:%H -n1 -- ../inter/local.py | grep -o '^.\{7\}') # doesn't work, returns empty string
$(info $$CUR_LOC_VERSION is [${CUR_LOC_VERSION}])
```

I am expecting it to show a commit hash but it returns empty string.

```
$CUR_LOC_VERSION is []
```

But the above command runs fine when running directly inside the shell (instead of calling through a Makefile.).

Any pointers highly appreciated.

## Directory structure.

```
.
|-- inter
|   |-- local.py
|
`-- vhdl
    |-- Makefile
```

Comment: What is the working directory when you execute this Makefile ? is `../inter/local.py` a path that falls within your git repo when relative to that wd ?

Comment: Could be a problem with '\' and nested substitutions; once by make, once by shell. Try adding extra '\' in the grep pattern.

Comment: Why do you use `grep`? Just output `format:%h` without any processing.

Comment: @LeGEC- I have updated the directory structure. The path ../inter/local.py falls within the git repo relative to the work directory.

Comment: @Andreas The issue seems to be in the git part and not in the grep part.

Comment: @phd can you please elaborate what you actually mean.

Comment: Then remove the grep part, for now. What does the git command produce, when you run it in the command line (i.e. without Make)?

Comment: @Beta, if I remove the grep part and run the git command on the command line, it provides the commit hash.

Comment: I don't wish to seem too inquisitive, but would you consider telling us what that hash actually is, and what happens when you remove the grep part *in the makefile?*

Comment: @beta on the command line, if I run `git log --pretty=format:%H -n1 -- ../inter/local.py |  grep -o '^.\{7\}`, I get `d020550`. If I remove the grep part, ie, run `git log --pretty=format:%H -n1 -- ../inter/local.py` I get `2a427ad8ad37aa26e6f97ebd99315d42e838fa4a`.

Comment: I think @Beta wants to know what happens when you remove the grep part _in the makefile_; what output do you get?  We believe you that the command line works :).  We need to debug what's wrong with the version in the makefile.

Comment: @MadScientist, sorry. When I remove the grep part in the Makefile and run it. I get `$CUR_LOC_VERSION is []`

Comment: And you get no error messages or anything like that?  If you type, at your shell prompt, `type -a git` does it show you're using any aliases or shell functions for git?  I really can't explain that.  I certainly can't reproduce this behavior on my system: it works fine.

Comment: If you test exactly this makefile, by itself, it fails?  Not as part of some larger makefile that you haven't shown us?  When you use `make --version` what do you get?  What operating system are you using?

Comment: Thanks @MadScientist for the help. `type -a git` outputs `git is /usr/bin/git`. `make --version` outputs 'GNU Make 4.0 Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu '. It seems that if I run the Makefile by itself, I can see what I expect to see. But when I run it as part of a larger Makefile, it breaks. I will need to investigate why it breaks as part of the larger Makefile system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't explain why your current version doesn't work.  But note, if you want to get a specific size of the abbreviated hash you can do that directly without needing to use grep.  Just run:

```
git log -n1 --format=%h --abbrev=7
```

The `%h` format option shows an abbreviated hash, and the `--abbrev` says how many characters to use.

Based on more investigation above, my suspicion is that your working directory when you run this is not what you think it is.  If I run `git log -n1 -- nosuchfile` (using a non-existent file) I don't get any error message, like I'd expect; I just get no output.  That's kind of confusing, but it leads me to believe that `../inter/local.py` doesn't exist when you run this `git` command.  Try adding `pwd` to your `shell` command so it prints out the working directory before running git:

```
CUR_LOC_VERSION:= $(shell pwd; git log --format=%h -n1 -- ../inter/local.py)
```

and see what the output is.

Comment: You are correct  @MadScientist. The file `../inter/local.py` was not accessible from my `pwd`. Thats explains the issue.  Thanks again for the help.